# How to recursively build a list of lists? Stuck on aggregating the sublists to a larger lists

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, f#

So I currently have a function which I have defined to count the number of occurrences in a column and I'd like to do that for N number of columns. The `stats` parameter is the column I'm analyzing and counting the occurrences through another function, `countNumber.` N is the number of columns I'm analyzing.

The function I've posted below currently returns a list [occurences, column Number N].

```
let rec subList stats n = 
  let list = []
  let newList = n::list
  if n = 0 then [] else (countNumber stats n)::newList
```

I would like to do this operation for each of my N columns and form a new list from all the sublists. The output should be something like: `[ [22, 103]; [36, 78]; [43, 13]; ...]` I'm stumped here on the recursive part.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: It would help us if you provided sample input and the source code for your countNumber function. Thanks

Comment: If `The stats parameter is the column I'm analyzing`, then what is the `subList` parameter?